# java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Communications link failure if too big a request

Tags: java, mysql

When my Java app tries to execute a really big update - 100K rows or so - it gets this error:

```
connection 1 failed: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 2008 ms ago.
```

How can I determine the limit that MySQL is imposing on the client?  Is the limit row-count-based or byte-based?

And how can I determine the size of a batch update?

Comment: It may actually be a connection timeout due to it taking too long to process the data. You may want to check on the configuration properties available to your JDBC driver.

Comment: @cjstehno Indeed; the client was setting a timeout of 2000ms when connectingg.  thx.